# How do I tell Windows 7 to never Launch Startup Repair

Tags: windows-7, boot, repair

I have a Windows 7 (64-bit) virtual machine that I primarily remote desktop into. Sometimes on boot something goes wrong and it displays the following DOS screen:

```
                             Windows Error Recovery
Windows Failed to start. A recent hardware of software change might be the cause.

If Windows files have been damaged or configured incorrectly, Startup Repair can help diagnose and fix the problem. If power was interrupted during startup, choose Start Windows Normally.
(Use the arrow keys to highlight your choice.)

 * Launch Startup Repair (recommended)
 * Start Windows Normally
```

The default option is `Launch Startup Repair` (which happens automatically after 30 seconds). How can I set it so that this *never* happens, and it always tries to `Start Windows Normally`?

Comment: See ["How does one skip 'Windows did not shut down successfully' in Win7-64?"](http://superuser.com/questions/255055).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Do this command:

> bcdedit /set {current}
>   bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures

Similar is

> bcdedit /set {default}
>   bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures

They can be the same if you are booted into the default load, so default would equal current.

For more information, the relevant Google search is "disable Windows Error Recovery" (minus the quotes).

Answer (score 8):

A better solution would be to implement the following line for the BCDedit.

```
bcdedit /set {default} bootstatuspolicy ignoreshutdownfailures
```

This way, only shutdown failures will be ignored and the system won't go in to recovery mode.  Recovery mode will still be available when the machine fails to boot properly and encounters other errors.

Answer (score 4):

At the command prompt enter the following:

```
bcdedit /set {default} recoveryenabled No
```

This will disable Startup Repair from automatically booting when there is a problem.

**However, beware:**

You'll have to get back into Windows as Admin to re-enable it. Just change the No to Yes in the above command

*Credit to 'busterh' in this [SevenForums.com thread](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/11336-disable-windows-startup-repair-default-option.html)*