# Change default action on "Windows failed to start" boot menu

Tags: windows-7, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I tell Windows 7 to never Launch Startup Repair](https://superuser.com/questions/299895/how-do-i-tell-windows-7-to-never-launch-startup-repair)

When a Microsoft Windows machine is interrupted (ie. powered down) while booting up, it will often display a recovery menu the next time it starts.

This menu gives you the options to start windows repair (the default) or to start windows normally.

Is there any way to set the default to start windows normally?