# How to set up a headless Windows 7 to handle start up repairs?

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

I need to automate a Windows 7 "Headless" computer. 
There is no user input available. How would I handle a case where a Start Up Repair dialogue is prompted after some for of system crash?

How would one set up a machine to attempt a repair without user input?

I know it's possible to disable the repair, with [this](https://superuser.com/questions/299895/how-do-i-tell-windows-7-to-never-launch-startup-repair) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/145600/how-does-one-skip-windows-did-not-shut-down-successfully-in-win7-64/255055#255055), but I'm basically looking to force the repair, if needed.

[Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/embedded/archive/2009/04/14/creating-headless-systems.aspx) is another discussion (the link reroutes, but the initial page is what I'm after). I'm looking for a way to move from a "Out-of-band" situation to an "In-band" situation.

Comment: If it fails to starts and you have a monitoring solution in place (which could be a user yelling 'thingy does not work. I already flipped the power switch a few dozen times!' then you could access the host via ILO, DRAC or VPRO. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HP_Integrated_Lights-Out, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dell_DRAC, http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/remote-support/implementation-of-intel-vpro-technology.html)

Comment: I need it to not use ANY user input, not even via a remote machine. But that could be helpful to other users.