# STOP Windows from launching startup repair

Tags: windows-7, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does one skip “Windows did not shut down successfully” in Win7-64?](https://superuser.com/questions/145600/how-does-one-skip-windows-did-not-shut-down-successfully-in-win7-64)

Currently when my computer loses power or shuts down unexpectedly it will power back on automatically when it regains power. The problem is that when it starts backup Windows defaults to launch the startup repair option unless otherwise directed.
[image]
 This normally wouldn't  be a problem but this particular computer that has the problem is mainly accessed remotely and I don't have direct access to it most of the time.

Is there a way to make the default option to start Windows normally vs the start up repair or completely circumvent this screen because 99% of the time I won't need a start up repair for this error.

The computer runs Windows 7 Ultimate OEM edition with Dell Bios 1.0.12

Comment: That was exactly that answer I was looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [link](https://superuser.com/questions/145600/how-does-one-skip-windows-did-not-shut-down-successfully-in-win7-64) that JdeBP points to perfectly solved my problem. I ran `command prompt` as adminstrator and entered:

```
bcdedit /set {current} bootstatuspolicy ignoreallfailures
```

After that I tested it by cutting power to the computer. When the power was restored it booted right into Windows with no error recovery screen.